# Error AttributeError: 'Block' object has no attribute 'sprites' - PYGAME

Tags: python, pygame

I am relativley new to pygame and have started coding my first game, 
I have a probelm at the moment when trying to collide the ball and the blocks, it comes up with this.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Robert Hartley\Documents\Python\PYGAME32BIT\Ball Game.py",      line 152, in <module>
deadblocks = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ball, block_group, True)
   File "C:\Users\Robert Hartley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1514, in spritecollide
for s in group.sprites():
 AttributeError: 'Block' object has no attribute 'sprites'
```

I don't know what i have done wrong and i've seen other people with this and it has been sorted with calling super().**init**(), but I've already done that, any help would be gladly accepted, thanks,

Here my full code - it probably isn't any good so any help or tips with that would also be nice :D

```
import pygame
import random
import math
blue=(0,0,255)
green = (0,255,0)
red = (255,0,0)
black=(0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
height = 600
width = 800
block_width = 64
block_height = 64
ball_width = 30
ball_height = 30
angle = 0
mousex = 100
mousey = 400
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Ball,self).__init__()   
        self.velx = 2
        self.vely = -1
        self.x = 370
        self.y = 530
        self.image = pygame.Surface([ball_width,ball_height])

        self.image.fill(red)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()



    def set_pos(self, x, y):
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def set_angle(self,angle):
        self.velx = math.cos(self.angleradi)
        self.vely = math.sin(self.angleradi)
        self.angleradi = math.radians(self.direction)
    def bounce(self):
        self.direction = math.degrees(angle)
        self.direction = (180 - self.direction) %360


    def update(self):


        self.x = self.x + self.velx
        self.y = self.y + self.vely


        if self.x <= 0 or self.x >= width-ball_width:
            self.velx = self.velx * -1
        if self.y<=0:        
            self.vely = self.vely * -1
        if self.y >= height- ball_height:
            self.x = 370
            self.y = 570
            self.velx = 0
            self.vely = 0

        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

        screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x,self.rect.y))
        if self.rect.x == 370 and self.rect.y ==570:
            return False
        else :
            return True





class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    pygame.init()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Block,self).__init__()

        self.r = random.randint(0,100)
        self.g = random.randint(0,100)
        self.b = random.randint(175,255)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([block_width, block_height])

        self.image.fill((self.r,self.g,self.b))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def set_pos(self,x,y):

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y



if __name__ == "__main__":

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])
    pygame.display.set_caption('Ballz')



    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fps = 120
    allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    #create the ball
    ball_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

    x = random.randint(0,600)
    y = random.randint(0, 200)
    ball = Ball()
    ball_group.add(ball)
    allsprites.add(ball)
    ball.set_pos(370,570)

    block_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    #create the blocks   
    for i in range(10):
        x = random.randint(0,600)
        x = x - x % 70 #rounds to the nearest 70
        y = random.randint(0, 200)
        y = y - y % 70
        block = Block()
        allsprites.add(block)
        block_group.add(block)
        block.set_pos(x, y)



while True :

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if ball.update() == False:
                mousex,mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                angle = math.atan((600 - mousey)/(mousex-370))





    screen.fill(black)     
    clock.tick(fps)
    deadblocks = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ball, block_group, True)


    for block_group in deadblocks:
        ball.bounce()





    allsprites.draw(screen)
    ball.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: If you want more tips about the code structure, make sure that the program works correctly and then post the complete code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused because you override the `block_group` variable in this line:

```
for block_group in deadblocks:
    ball.bounce()
```

`pygame.sprite.spritecollide` returns a list of sprites, so if it contains sprites and you loop over it, the name `block_group` will be bound to a sprite object and it does not refer to a group object anymore. That means the next time you call `pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ball, block_group, True)` the game will crash because the second argument has to be a group not a sprite.

Change the name in the for loop to fix the issue.